# if value = X return boolean value with React

Tags: reactjs

I have a props.countryCode which value is say 'GB' and what I would like to do is tick a checkbox if it is GB and leave it unchecked if it isn't

I've managed to get this concept working great for boolean values like this for example which will tick a checkbox if the 'showErrors' value is true.

```
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={props.showErrors==='true'} /></label>
```

So is it possible to do something like .. if the country code = GB then return true?

So something like this (but you know .. not terrible)

```
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={props.countryCode.value = 'GB' : props.countryCode.value==='true'} />
```

Comment: You just want to test that props.countryCode.value==='GB'?  Note multiple equal signs.

Comment: Testing this I couldn't get anything, console logging it it was returning null, so I removed the '.value' part and it started returning 'GB' as before ... so strangely I have actually got this working now I want it to work with just the following - <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={props.countryCode === 'GB'} /> ... which is what I couldn't get working to start with, maybe there was just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  defaultChecked={props.countryCode === 'GB'}
/>
```

which automatically returns a `boolean` value.

Comment: Testing this I couldn't get anything, console logging it it was returning null, so I removed the '.value' part and it started returning 'GB' as before ... so strangely I have actually got this working now I want it to work with just the following - <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={props.countryCode === 'GB'} /> ... which is what I couldn't get working to start with, maybe there was just a typo

Comment: @NeilKelsey I wrote my answer based on what you typed in your question. I can change it as well :)

Comment: Yeah well it works so that's the answer! (I thought I tried that and it didn't work which is why I created this question ... so I'm a little confused / annoyed / bemused) .. but hey it works, happy days! :-)